# Average of Smallest and Largest

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been given a question that

> Write a C++ function maxMinAve. This function is passed a vector
>   parameter and returns the average of the smallest and largest value
>   stored in the array list. Write an additional code fragment to test
>   this function. Include any declarations and initialization statements
>   necessary to test the function.

I am not asking for any solution I just want to know that what does this mean

> the average of the smallest and largest value

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Which part is unclear, the math or the C++ part?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt C++ only ... just don't want code ...

Comment: Okay, the part you mention means that you should calculate this average in C++. It's hard to go any further, because that's basically all. Now, if you really have a C++ problem like defining a function, you really need to pick up a C++ tutorial, because nothing in that assignment is unusual or really difficult (for a C++ assignment, that is). Don't even think of coming here in the hope of having someone else do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess (largest + smallest)/2